# Optimizing locality and minimal cycle lenght in bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Consider a regular bipartite graph $G(A,B)$ where the degree of every vertices in $A$ is $d_A$ and in $B$ is $d_B$.

We denote the elements of $A$ by the natural numbers. That is, $A = \lbrace 0, 1, \ldots, |A| - 1 \rbrace$.

An element $b \in B$ is said to be local if it is connected to consecutive elements of $A$. The locality $L(G)$ of a graph is the number of local elements of $B$.

For given $d_A, d_B$ and $|A|$, I want to find a $(d_A, d_B)-$regular graph $G$ that maximise the product $L(G) C(G)$ where $C(G)$ is the length of the smallest cycle in $G$.

It seems hard to find such optimal graph, but I would be happy with any graph that is close to it.

To be honest, I have no idea how to solve this problem except generating random graphs and hoping to find a good solution. Therefore, any help would be appreciate, including good references that can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to fix $|A|$ or $|B|$ or something, else there may not be a maximum. For example, let $G$ be an even circle graph with $2n$ vertices. $G$ is $(2,2)$-regular and (for an appropriate labeling of $A$) has $L(G) C(G) = 2n(n-1)$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I will edit.